# Hibernate :"detached entity passed to persist" error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I can not understand what's wrong in my code, in practice, in my system I want to make an assessment for a specific curriculum, I would like to save memory this assessment, but, when I try to save it, the system take me this error:

complete stacktrace.

```
GRAVE: 
   Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path          [/orion-web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is    org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@165b124 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@150c296 expression = inserimentoRecruitingController.salvaRecruiting(), resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'valutazione' of flow 'valutazioneCandidato-flow' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: [color=#FF0000]detached entity passed to persist: it.dstech.dms.cigno.jpa.model.impl.CurriculumVitaeEntityImpl[/color]
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
   at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
   at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
   at $Proxy30.persist(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
   at $Proxy30.persist(Unknown Source)
   at it.dstech.dms.cigno.service.core.service.impl.recruiting.RecruitingServiceImpl.saveRecruiting(RecruitingServiceImpl.java:55)
   at it.dstech.dms.cigno.service.core.service.impl.recruiting.RecruitingServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1e5f6a9c.invoke(<generated>)
   at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
   at it.dstech.dms.cigno.service.core.service.impl.recruiting.RecruitingServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6a801cce.saveRecruiting(<generated>)
   at it.dstech.dms.orion.swf.manager.impl.GestioneRecruitingWFManagerImpl.doInsertRecruiting(GestioneRecruitingWFManagerImpl.java:45)
   at it.dstech.dms.cigno.model.InserimentoRecruitingController.salvaRecruiting(InserimentoRecruitingController.java:38)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:110)
   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
   at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
   at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
   at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
   at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
   at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
   at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.ActionTransitionCriteria.test(ActionTransitionCriteria.java:82)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionCriteriaChain.test(TransitionCriteriaChain.java:71)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.canExecute(Transition.java:195)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:211)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
   at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
   at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
   at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
   at      

      org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:   539)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

these are the classes with hibernate mappings, in red are the relationships where the problem occurs

```
 @Entity
   @Table(name = "CGN_CURRVIT")
   public class CurriculumVitaeEntityImpl extends AbstractJpaEntity implements
      CurriculumVitaeEntity {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersonaEntityImpl.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "PERSONA")
   private PersonaEntity persona;


   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", targetEntity = RecruitingEntityImpl.class)
   @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
   private List<RecruitingEntity> recruitingEntity;
   `




 `
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "CGN_RECR")
   public class RecruitingEntityImpl extends AbstractJpaEntity implements
      RecruitingEntity {

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "RECRUITING_ID")
   private Long recruitingId;

   @Column(name = "GIUDIZIO")
   private Long giudizio;       //valore da 1 a 5

   @Column(name = "NOTE")
   private String note;

   @OneToOne(targetEntity = ValutazioneEntityImpl.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =           

   FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "VALUTAZIONE")
   private ValutazioneEntity valutazione = new ValutazioneEntityImpl();


  @OneToOne(targetEntity = CurriculumVitaeEntityImpl.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
   @JoinColumn(name = "CURRICULUM_ID")
   @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
   private CurriculumVitaeEntity curriculumVitae;

   .......
   }
```

This is the class which provides data storage on the database

public class RecruitingServiceImpl extends AbstractDmsService implements
      RecruitingService {

public void saveRecruiting(RecruitingEntity recruiting) {

```
  /* in curriculumVitae ci sono tutti i dati da salvare */

  /*
   * Cerco il persistenceStatus dal db e lo setto al curriculum vitae e
   * alla persona associata
   */
  PersistenceStatus persistenceStatus = this.entityManager.find(
        PersistenceStatusImpl.class, 1L);
  recruiting.setPersistenceStatus(persistenceStatus);

  ValutazioneTipologicalEntity valutazioneEntity = valutazioneService
        .findByDescription(recruiting.getValutazione().getValutazione()
              .getDescription());
  recruiting.getValutazione().setValutazione(valutazioneEntity);

  recruiting.getValutazione()
        .setPersistenceStatus(persistenceStatus);

  entityManager.persist(recruiting);

  }
```